# NLog in ASP.NET MVC5 does only log the first entries

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging, asp.net-mvc-5, nlog

In my ASP.net MVC5 application, I have to use NLog.

If I open the appliaction on my development-machine with the built-in IIS-express from visual studio, everything works very well.

But if I publish the program to our testing-environment-IIS (An IIS 7), strange things happen:

At application-start, everything works as intended. Every logging-entry is being logged.

But as soon as my application performs the next request, for example a request to `/Controller/Method2`, it doesn't log anything.

I can surf along on the application and no logs are being written, except once at application start the first few entries, and this only, if there was no previous .log-file.

For me, it seems like a NLog-Config problem.

My config, as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true" >

  <!-- http://nlog-project.org/wiki/File_target -->
  <!-- http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Layout_Renderers -->

  <targets>

    <target name="LogFile_Debug" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} [${processid} : ${threadid}] [${identity} - ${windows-identity}] ${level} - ${message} ${exception:Format=tostring}"
            fileName="D:/Logs/debug.log"
            archiveFileName="D:/Logs/Archive/debug.{#}.log"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveNumbering="Rolling"
            maxArchiveFiles="60"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            encoding="ISO-8859-1">
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LogFile_Debug" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have tested with `keepFileOpen="true"` and `keepFileOpen="false"`, with `autoReload="true"` and `autoReload="false"` and nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your logging code in Controller and Controller.Method2 look like?

Comment: Nothing special. It's used by `logger.Info("LogText");` or `logger.Warn("Warn");` It's initialized throigh the `GetCurrentClassLogger();`. But then, why does it work on my local dev-machine, only on the productive IIS it doesn't?

Comment: I assume the user your test-environment app is running under has permissions to write to the configured directory.

Comment: Try turning off `concurrentWrites`

Comment: @tster Solved: Well, with a workaround. The problem were concurrent writes, and my testing-iis-pool wasn't capable of doing so, I have no clue why. On the productive environment everything worked fine. I'd like to provide you with the necessary configurations, but I have no access to it, sorry... I hope you find a solution soon.

Comment: @ManuToMatic,  I ended up finding my problem.  I was using a library which did some manual NLog configuration inside of it and it was overwriting the static NLog configuration on LogManager.   I changed the library to build a LogFactory instead of setting up a config on LogManager.